# How to create a container component with access to some children's values?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component wrapper like this:

```
 <SpecialWrapper config={}>
    {this.props.children}
 </SpecialWrapper>
```

The idea is to use it like this:

```
 <SpecialWrapper>

       // whatever other components you have

       <SpecialInput1/>
       <SpecialInput1/>

       <Button onClick={()=> SpecialWrapper.methodWhereValuesNeeded()}

 </SpecialWrapper>
```

Is it possible to somehow have access to the values of my special inputs in my "methodWhereValuesNeeded" method?

Comment: Does [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) help?

Answer (score 1):

You could manage the state for the specialInput within the wrapper component and pass a function for updating the state as a prop to the special Input

```
functionForUpdatingWrapperState = (newValue) => {
    this.state.SpecialInput1Value = newValue;
}

<SpecialWrapper>

   // whatever other components you have

   <SpecialInput1/>
   <SpecialInput1 updateValueFunction={functionForUpdatingWrapperState}/>

   <Button onClick={()=> SpecialWrapper.methodWhereValuesNeeded()}

 </SpecialWrapper>
```

Comment: You should use `setState({...this.state, SpecialInput1Value: newValue})` since it's a state.

Comment: @QuentinGrisel I used to using mobX for state management so I'm not entirely familiar with the built in state. Thank you I'll update my answer

Comment: You're welcome dude. This answer is correct by the way, you need to handle your value in the parent, or use a context

Comment: I was thinking of context as well because the idea of the Special input is to not be controlled by me. E.g. I create a library of components with some functionality when they are wrapped